# Android camera exposure

Tags: android, camera

I am facing issues with getExposureCompensation() and
getExposureCompensationStep() apis. Whenever I call these two apis, it
throws a null pointer exception. When i use the
getExposureCompensation after using setExposureCompensation() api,
then it works fine. But in the case of getExposureCompensationStep(),
i dont have a choice.

Your opinion and suggestion in this matter will be appreciated.

Thanks
Nawab

Comment: How are you acquiring the parameters? You should post some of your code, and your stack trace. I'm assuming your Camera.Parameters object is null.

Comment: i cant show you the stack trace at the moment but i can tell you that when it tries to parse the string for float value of  "KEY_EXPOSURE", it finds it null and so a nullpointer exception occurs. This is a bit of snippet of my code:-                 camera camera = Camera.open();                                      Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
int expcomp = params.getExposureCompensation();
float expstep = params.getExposureCompensationStep();              The complete code i cant paste right now as its there in my other workplace system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: <strike>There's your problem. :)</strike> Or not... >.>

[`Camera`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) does not have a `getExposureCompensation()` or `getExposureCompensationStep()` method. Those are methods for your [`Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) object! Try changing it to:

```
int expcomp = params.getExposureCompensation();
float expstep = params.getExposureCompensationStep();
```

Comment: ohhh that was a typing mistake...i edited the comment and rectified that mistake in the comment....i am using params.getExposureCompensation() and params.getExposureCompensationStep();
only. They are failing actually.

Comment: Are you able to get/set other Parameters? Try stepping through the debugger and make sure params isn't null; the only way you'd be getting an NPE is if that's the case, I'm fairly certain.

Comment: i am able to set the exposure compensation and then able to get it. but without setting it, i am not able to get it. Also i am not able to get the compensation step. When i debug it, i find the params object proper. The issue looks like some parameters for camera are not initialized and so referencing it causing the issue. But there is no way to initialize the camera parameters from our side. I feel it should be initialized to default value once we call Camera.open().

Comment: Interesting. Honestly sounds like a bug to me, but I have no experience using the camera, really. As just a wild shot, try calling camera.setParameters(params); before the get() calls. It shouldn't change anything, really, but there is some documented weirdness with how the parameters are set, so it's worth a shot.

Comment: Ok tomorrow when i will be at my work system, i will try this out. lets see if this works out. But the way its behaving, it is insinuating that it might. Thanks for your views and ideas....i will let you know if it works or any update on it.

Comment: So are you using an emulator or an actual device, out of curiosity?

Comment: I think my problem was related to the hardware. The hardware needs to support these features explicitly then only these apis will work fine. I used the application on one phone, although it had the exposure adjustment feature implemented but these apis were failing, but later on i used these apis on another target and they worked fine on this one. Thanks for your support.

Comment: No problem, wish I had a real answer for ya though! The methods just shouldn't fail this way, even if the hardware doesn't support it. :( I guess you could just wrap it in a try/catch, and catch the NPE, but it still seems like there's something definitely wrong.